# Is there an expected delay between publishing a new version and it being consumable in a maven repositories

Tags: maven, mvn-repo

I'm comparing some features of different software repository solutions

I would like to know if there is any expected delay between my CI tool publishes a new version of a lib to a remote maven repository like [mavenrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/), [maven central](https://search.maven.org/), [Google's Maven Repository](https://maven.google.com/) or any other similar and the time that new version is fully available to be consumed.

I couldn't find any specific documentation mentioned something like that.

Comment: mavenrepository.com is not a maven repo it's a aggregator website for maven libraries from other sites.

Comment: If you publish to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) where https://search.maven.org is the search engine for it...it can take a while while the artifacts are visible (depends where you publish) https://central.sonatype.org/ apart from that in which way comparing repository solutions you should go for comparison of Sonatype Nexus, Frogs Artifactory ?